# Using if in view.xml Appcelerator Titanium

Tags: android, ios, xml, titanium, appcelerator

```
<ListSection sec="fav" if="Alloy.CFG.favourite.enabled === true">
        <ListItem myTitle:text="L('fav')" slug="newsrizeFav" template="regularItem" />
</ListSection>
```

I am using if property in `view.xml` in titanium it works perfectly on android but on IOS
if `Alloy.CFG.favourite.enabled = true` their is no problem but 
if `Alloy.CFG.favourite.enabled = false`
titanium throws an exception

```
"Error: Invalid type passed to function"
```

Comment: Sdk version? i'm test with 5.2.2 and it worked perfectly

Comment: try to replace `if="Alloy.CFG.favourite.enabled === true"` by `if=Alloy.CFG.favourite.enabled`

Comment: I already tried that and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I just had Alloy 1.8.5 compile this and it results in:

```
if (true === Alloy.CFG.favourite.enabled) {
    $.__views.__alloyId67 = Ti.UI.createListSection({
        id: "__alloyId67"
    });
}
```

That should work fine on both iOS and Android. I think the error originates from something related, not this particular attribute itself. Doesn't the exception list the actual line number so you can debug (using the generated code in `/Resources`)?

Comment: No it doesn't print any numbers

Comment: So the error is just `"Error: Invalid type passed to function"` and nothing more? Try leaving out pieces of your XML step by step to pin point the exact issue then.